# No same height of content and bullet in li

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a list

```
<ul class="styled-list">
  <li>some text</li>
</ul>
```

and then I have css

```
.styled-list-arrow li:before {
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    font-size: small;
    content: "\e315";
    margin-left: -1.4em;
    width: 1.3em;
}
```

all works fine but one problem is, that li content is not on same height as li bullet. I don't know where can be a problem.

----------Edit--------------

I need move bullet little bit down

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: from a quick copy/paste of your code the above works fine. It's possibly somewhere else in your code where the problem is? Though   `vertical-align: middle;` might help

Comment: A [mcve] might be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code to the :before pseudo element:

```
vertical-align: bottom;
```

Also watch your class names. You have 'styled-list' and 'styled-list-arrow li'